# Return parent method from within block

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Hi I'm new to using blocks in Objective-C

What I think I want is the following:

```
- (void) iNeedAToken {

  NSString *token = [self theMethodThatShouldReturnTheToken];

}

- (NSString) theMethodThatShouldReturnTheToken {

  [myAwesomeAsyncMethod success:^(id JSON) {

        NSString *token = [JSON objectForKey:@"FOO"];
        return token;

    }]

}
```

Is this possible? Or is this the wrong logic all together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing async with synchronous code. You're `theMethodThatShouldReturnTheToken` already returned (you're missing a return value) before the block passed to `success` finishes.

Best bet would be to continue your process from the success block.

```
- (void) tokenRequestContext1
{
    [self requestToken:^(NSString *token) {
        // do something with token
    }];
}

- (void) requestToken:(void(^)(NSString *))tokenBlock
{
    [myAwesomeAsyncMethod success:^(id JSON) {
        NSString *token = [JSON objectForKey:@"FOO"];
        if (tokenBlock) {
            tokenBlock(token);
        }
    }];
}
```

You start by calling `requestToken`. This will start the async request for your token. Some time might pass, but eventually `doSomethingWithToken` will be called where you can use the received token.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought of initially, but this is seems like tight coupling to me. What I want to do with the token depends on the context. So what I want is a method that returns the token to its caller.. If I'm seeing this wrong, please do tell :)

Comment: Async methods will never return the async result to a caller. You'll always have to use continuation blocks. You can make that reusable by accepting another block to execute on success but that still won't make it look like synchronous code like your opening post.

Comment: updated my answer, for each context you want to use the token in create a method similar to `tokenRequestContext1`. However know that that method already returned, and you can only use the token in the scope of that `^(NSString *token){ [...] }` block.

Answer (score -1):

There is a description of way to wait until complition block will be finished: http://omegadelta.net/2011/05/10/how-to-wait-for-ios-methods-with-completion-blocks-to-finish/

Answer (score -1):

Regular version of this code is:

```
- (void) iNeedAToken {
  [self theMethodThatShouldReturnTheToken:^(id res){ token = res;}];
  NSString *token = [self theMethodThatShouldReturnTheToken];

}

- (void) theMethodThatShouldReturnTheToken:(void  (^)(id res)result) {

  [myAwesomeAsyncMethod success:^(id JSON) {

        NSString *token = [JSON objectForKey:@"FOO"];
        result(token);

    }]

}
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the syntax on this line `- (NSString) theMethodThatShouldReturnTheToken:(void  (^)(id res)result)`

Comment: Still not working. It's (still) complaining that it is expecting an `)` in the last part